# check perforce repeatedly after every 1 min .

Tags: linux, perforce

I have a p4 server where people continuously make commits  . I do not have access to that server .  I cannot install anything on my linux box nor is the perforce setup accessible to me.

Whenever some one makes a commit in an area we need to do 4 things which are done in a shell script . Currently i do it manually .
Can this process be automated with some script ? I was trying to fetch last changelist number & doing stuff but then i realised may be there was some script already present .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share some code! Make an attempt! Start somewhere, and then improve it. As a first attempt, write a simple script that retrieves the last changelist number (`p4 changes -m 1`) and put it in a cron job, and get that working. Then expand on that to build the tool you need.

Answer (score 1):

The classic example of this type of thing is the email review daemon:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/lester-cheung-p4review/files/main/p4review.py

The general approach is to get the set of changes made since you last checked, do whatever you need to do, and then update a counter to indicate the last change you checked.  The review daemon uses a counter on the server, but if you don't have permissions to create/update your own counter on the server you could track this locally (in a file etc).